# WordPress Custom Page Blog Template Pagination Problem (Pagination Not Displaying)

Tags: plugins, php, functions

My website doesn't display pagination no matter what I do or try. Can you help me, please? Tried a lot of different codes and Plugins but no dice.

Here is the code for test template:

```
<?php
/* Template Name: No SideBar - Testing */
get_header();
?>

<style>
    #outPopUp {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        padding-top: 25px !important;
        padding-bottom: 25px !important;
        color: black;
        width: 100% !important;
        max-width: 480px !important;
    }

    .page-numbers {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        margin: 0 2px 0 0;
        border: 1px solid #eee;
        line-height: 1;
        font-size: 12px;
        border-radius: 1px;
        font-weight: 600;
        color: black !important;
    }

    .page-numbers.current,
    a.page-numbers:hover {
        background: #CA003D;
    }
</style>

<main>
    <div class="banner" style="background-image: url(https://www.mgc.com.tr/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/mgc-legal-pubclications-upper-banner-v2-scaled.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="page-inner knowlege">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 in detail" style="padding: 15px 55px;">
                    <p><?php
                        if (function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb')) {
                            yoast_breadcrumb('<p id="breadcrumbs">', '</p>');
                        }
                        ?></p>
                    <h1><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h1>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="posts">
            <div class="head">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 d-flex align-items-center">
                            xxxxxxxxxxxx
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="all" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="all-tab">
                    <div class="items">
                        <div class="container">
                            <ul id="listPage" class="row item-list">

                                <?php
                                $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : ((get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1);
                                $args = array(
                                    'post_type' => 'post',
                                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                                    'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
                                    'order' => 'DESC',
                                    'orderby' => 'date',
                                    'paged' => $paged
                                );
                                $result = new WP_Query($args);
                                ?>

                                <?php if ($result->have_posts()) : while ($result->have_posts()) : $result->the_post(); ?>

                                        <li class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 column items-col">
                                            <div class="item">
                                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="color: #f59c0c;" class="d-flex align-items-center">
                                                    <div class="in">
                                                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between author">
                                                            <div class="author-name col-7">
                                                                <br><br>
                                                                <?php
                                                                $author = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'postAuthor', true);
                                                                if (!empty($author)) {
                                                                    foreach ($author as $author_item => $item) {
                                                                        echo get_the_title($item) . '<br>';
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                                ?>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="rank col-5 text-end">
                                                                <br><br>
                                                                <?php
                                                                $konu = get_the_category(get_the_ID());
                                                                foreach ($konu as $item) {
                                                                    $konu_name = $item->name;
                                                                }
                                                                echo $konu_name;
                                                                ?>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <figure>
                                                            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('full'); ?>" alt="<?php the_post_thumbnail_caption(); ?>" class="img-fit">
                                                        </figure><br>
                                                        <div class="title"><?php echo title_limit(40); ?></div>
                                                        <p><?php echo icerik_limit(get_the_content(), 150); ?></p>
                                                        <p><span style="float:left;"><time datetime="<?php echo get_the_date('c'); ?>" itemprop="datePublished"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></time></span><span style="float:right;">Devamını Oku >></span></p>
                                                        <br><br><br>
                                                    </div>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                                    <div class="container" id="outPopUp">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <?php the_posts_pagination(array(
                                                'mid_size' => 1,
                                                'prev_text' => __('<', 'textdomain'),
                                                'next_text' => __('>', 'textdomain'),
                                            )); ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a page template for listing posts? If this is supposed to be your blog you should be using home.php or index.php, not a custom page template.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. We have index.php, but that's our home page, and that's different, we are not displaying blog posts on our home page. We have a separate page for blog posts.

Comment: home.php, despite the name, is used for the blog, not the homepage. Set the page you’re using for the blog in Settings > Reading and then use home.php for the blog.